# How do I call the grandparent's constructor (because the parent's constructor is not defined)?

Tags: perl, oop, constructor, super

I believe, the canonical way to call the parent's class' constructor in Perl is:

```
package Child;
our @ISA = 'Parent';

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my @args = @_;
  my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@args);
  return $self;
}
```

However, this construct doesn't seem to work if `Parent` does not explicitely define a `new` function (but `Grandparent` does).

This is the case, for example, with `Net::FTP::File`.

`tq84_ftp.pm`:

```
package tq84_ftp;

use warnings;
use strict;

our @ISA = qw(Net::FTP::File);

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = $class->SUPER::new('localhost')
     or die($@);
  return $self;
}    

1;
```

`script.pl`:

```
use tq84_ftp;
tq84_ftp->new();
```

Output:

```
Can't locate package Net::FTP::File for @tq84_ftp::ISA at tq84_ftp.pm line 10.
Can't locate package Net::FTP::File for @tq84_ftp::ISA at tq84_ftp.pm line 10.
Can't locate object method "new" via package "tq84_ftp" at tq84_ftp.pm line 10.
```

How do I specify that I want Perl to find the correct (here: grantparent's) `new` function?

Comment: You really shouldn't be asking this. Of course it's possible, as most things are in Perl. But the design of your class structure is badly at fault and you shouldn't be writing code to get around it.

Comment: You certainly can help me to point me towards what I should be asking instead.

Comment: You need help with your class structure which, if you're really at a loss to know how to proceed, involves publishing all of your relevant code. Most likely you will need to employ a contractor. If there are only one or two classes then we may be able to help you here if you show everything you have, but I think that's unlikely.

Comment: Why can't the parent simply inherit from the grandparent everything that is required by its child?

Comment: This is pretty much what I have. Why the parent cannot simply inherit from the grandparent everything that is required by its child, I cannot tell, because I have neither written `Net::FTP::File` nor `Net::FTP`.

Comment: It's nothing like what you have. You don't show your main program at all, and you don't say what files your sources are in. You have a thing with `package Child` that inherits from `Parent` which isn't defined anywhere. You also have a thing with `package tq84_ftp` (which in all decency should be `package TQ84::FTP`) which inherits from `Net::FTP::File`. Those two things are totally unrelated, and I can't think what relationship you might imagine between them. I would try to help if I could see you mistake, but there is only nonsense.

Comment: When I referred to `Child` and `Parent`, I used these terms as generic names to point at their relationship, and not, of course, as  as actually used package names. Think `Net::FTP::File` and `Net::FTP` as their actual real world concrete counterparts.
The problem I want to solve is that I have lot's of code that uses `Net::FTP::File`, but If I could change the way that its `new` actually handles a particular thing, I wouldn't have to change the whole litany of existing code.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: I have explained that what you have written is potentially two unrelated modules, so there is no problem to find. If your real code is significantly different then you should reduce the problem in the manner of a [*Short, Self Contained, Correct Example*](http://sscce.org/) that we can run and experience the same issues.

Comment: @Borodin, I have posted an example that is Short and Self Contained, and, if the `...` are filled in with username and password, is also correct (in that it compiles and exhibits the behaviour I try to get around, not in that it does what I want).

Comment: No, it's not self-contained. It doesn't demonstrate the problem as-is. Fixed.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Reading between the lines, it seems you assume that `Net::FTP::File` is a subclass of `Net::FTP`. **It is not**.

Comment: @SinanÜnür, I did, in fact, assume exactly that. Thanks for pointing out what I was missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you assume that `Net::FTP::File` is a subclass of `Net::FTP` and, therefore

```
my $self = $class->SUPER::new('localhost') ...
```

should invoke `Net::FTP`'s `new` method.

However, in fact, `Net::FTP::File` ***does not*** inherit from `Net::FTP`. Instead, it redefines some methods in `Net::FTP`. Therefore, if your class inherits from `Net::FTP::File`, it will not be child of `Net::FTP`.

You can see this easily if you look at the [source code for `Net::FTP`](https://metacpan.org/source/DMUEY/Net-FTP-File-0.06/File.pm). Note that there is no `use base 'Net::FTP'` or `use parent 'Net::FTP'` or `our @ISA = qw( Net::FTP )` below:

```
package Net::FTP::File;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;

# ...

sub Net::FTP::pretty_dir {
    shift;
    my $newp = shift;
    if ( defined $newp ) {
        $pretty = $newp;
        $DirProcHash{cols} = $cols{pretty}  if $pretty;
        $DirProcHash{cols} = $cols{utility} if !$pretty;
    }
    return $pretty;
}

# ...

sub Net::FTP::isfile {
    my $ftp = shift;
    return 1 if $ftp->exists(@_) && !$ftp->isdir(@_);
    0;
}
```

etc etc.

Answer (score 6):

> *However, this construct doesn't seem to work if `Parent` does not explicitely define a new function (but `Grandparent` does).*

Not true.

```
$ perl -E'
   package Grandparent {
      sub new { CORE::say(__PACKAGE__) }
   }

   package Parent {
      our @ISA = "Grandparent";
   }

   package Child {
      our @ISA = "Parent";
      sub new { my $class = shift; $class->SUPER::new(); }
   }

   Child->new();
'
Grandparent
```

---

> *`Can't locate package Net::FTP::File`*

This a warning obtained when you try to inherit from a class that hasn't been declared. Specifically, you are trying to use Net::FTP::File without having loaded it.

Replace

```
our @ISA = 'Net::FTP::File';
```

with

```
use Net::FTP::File qw( );
our @ISA = 'Net::FTP::File';
```

or with

```
use parent 'Net::FTP::File';
```

---

> *`Can't locate object method "new" via package "tq84_ftp"`*

This message is a bit unclear, but it's due to the fact that `Net::FTP::File->new` doesn't exist. Net::FTP::File isn't a class, much less a subclass of Net::FTP. It has no methods, much less a `new` method. It makes no sense to inherit from Net::FTP::File.

You appear to want to create a Net::FTP object, so replace

```
use parent 'Net::FTP::File';
```

with

```
use parent 'Net::FTP';
```

---

Finally, you want to load Net::FTP::File for the methods it adds to Net::FTP objects (which includes object of classes that inherit from Net::FTP). To do that, simply add

```
use Net::FTP::File qw( );
```

Comment: Added to my answer. In the future, please post code that you actually ran, and please provide the actual output from that code.

Comment: @ikegame Thanks for the effort you put to answer my question. After a day too long I must have made a sloppy mistake, although I was sure I copy/pasted the correct error message. Anyway, I will do better next time.